# My wordpress blog doesn't populate facebook's news feed properly

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I'm new to facebook and wordpress, but need to figure this out.

How exactly does the news feed on facebook extract information from the url you provide? What does it look for?

Right now on my blog there is the content and a side bar with an author bio. The bio ends up being the text the news feed extracts and not the post's content.

Perhaps someone out there can explain to me how I should "optimize" my blog so that  the posts' content does show up.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your newsfeed in a RSS reader and see what's already included in the feed. Post content is already included in a WordPress feed, unless you're running a feed plugin that changes it: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

See http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=408 for FB feed help.

Comment: Thanks. I know wordpress has its rss feed for posts. But does it have one for just one post?

Comment: Thanks. I know wordpress has its rss feed for posts. Bbut does the newsfeed use that? for example if you take a url froma blog like www.example.com/the_blog_post/ and throw it into newsfeed, it'll parse out the content properly.

Comment: Well, if you put the URL in a post, then the URL is available in that post in the feed. But if you assign the one post a certain category - and only that post - then you you will see only that post in the category feed.

Comment: im confused. sorry. When you enter the url of a post or any other url facebook parses out content for a post on your wall I think. Im wondering how it obtains that info. Right now the rss feed looks fine so I dont think facebook takes the rss feed.